# web push - force SW and GMC_ID update

Tags: javascript, service-worker, web-push

I would like migrate web push users to my custom web push service. How can I force update SW (another filename; unregister old and register new) and gcm_sender_id (manifest.json)?

Comment: please create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: https://github.com/Minishlink/web-push-php-example/tree/master/src

Answer (score 0):

You can register a service worker with a new name to bypass caching. In any case if you have the correct HTTP cache settings, then you can simply edit the content of the service worker and call register to update it.